# This an + bnlog2(n) + cn3 = k, finding n here for bigger input is not working properly

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization, equation

I had to solve a problem in a exam. But it couldn't pass all the test cases. It was this equation.

an + bnlog2(n) + cn3 = k where a,b,c,k are given. That position can be max 2^63 -1

suppose the input is

> input:
>
> 2 1 1 12167000368000
>
> 2 1 1 188000000000000
>
> output:
>
> 23000
>
> 0

this is my solution

```
#include<stdio.h>

long long Log2n(long long n)
{
     return (n > 1)? 1 + Log2n(n/2): 0;
 }

int main(){
  long long a,b,c,k, pos, flag = 0;
   scanf("%lld%lld%lld%lld",&a,&b,&c,&k);
   for(int i=0; i<100000000; i++){
        pos = a*i + b*i*Log2n(i)+ c*(i*i*i);
          if(pos == k){
             printf("%lld ",i);
               flag = 1;
                break;
              }
         }
    if(flag == 0){
      printf("0");
    }
  return 0;
 }
```

like small inputs 2 1 1 36 it's giving the right input. But when the input of k is big size or the number is not this it's not working properly.

I think my iteration has a problem. How many times this iteration should go on? or  is there any better solution to find this n value?

Comment: meowgoesthedog I understand. but how can I improve this?

Comment: What is "big size"?  You have provided example input that _works_; how about being specific about what does _not work_?  And what in the world is a "TLE"!?  Your title suggests "TLE", while your text body just says "not working properly".  Be explicit.

Comment: @Clifford  actually I dont know for which input its not working as the test case were hidden. But suppose for input 2 1 1 1 it should have print 0. but it will take too much time give that.

Comment: 100000000 no of iteration??? Are you getting any output with this?

Comment: Is this really "an exam", or just one of those pointless on-line judge competitions?  Either way, the point of the question is presumably to come up with something a but cleverer than brute-force.  Seems to be testing your maths expertise rather then your coding expertise - not a bad thing perhaps, but not necessarily an SO question.

Comment: @Clifford  actually that exam was on on-line judge competition

Comment: You should (IMO) be examined by real people.

Comment: Please specify the range of the input variables `a b c k`, as suggested below.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog what i can remember was that position can be max 2^63 -1

Comment: What about `a b c`? Their allowed ranges are important too, especially if they can be negative (which you haven't specified).

Comment: no  they were only positive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `a*i + b*i*Log2n(i)+ c*i*i*i` is mostly the same as `(a + b*Log2n(i)+ c*i*i) * i`.

This means (to reduce the risk of overflow) you can do:

```
    if(k % i == 0) {
        pos_divi = a + b*Log2n(i)+ c*i*i;
        if(pos_divi == k / i) {
             printf("%lld ",i);
             flag = 1;
             break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `i` is declared as `int`, `(i*i*i)` will overflow and invoke undefined behaviour.

You should declare `i` as `long long`or cast `i` to `long long` in the calculation of `pos`.

```
 for(int i=0; i<100000000; i++)
```

should be

```
 for(long long i=0; i<100000000; i++)
```

The limit `100000000` seems a little bit arbitrary and should be adjusted, since even with `long long` there can be overflows.

The change to `long long` of course is no general solution, but will work for the test case. The type which should be used heavily depends on the domain of the input variables.

Comment: how do you know `long long int` is enough ? That really a bad long term solution.

Comment: @Stargateur It strongly depends on the input domains which are not given, so no one can be sure. But this expression does overflow for the test case, therefore i suggested to use a type with larger range.

Comment: @Osiris: A built-in type with larger range will have significantly worse precision (e.g. 53 bits of precision for `double` rather than the 64 bits you'd hope you might get with `unsigned long long`) and give the wrong answer because of inadequate precision. If the range of `i` can't be reduced (so that `i` is always less than 2642246) you have to use "larger than 64-bit" integers, which (in practice) means creating it yourself (e.g. `uint32_t my128bitInteger[4]`).

Comment: @Brendan I never suggested to use floating point variables, since they clearly should not be used for this problem (and many other int problems). I also do not "hope to might get" 64 bits with `long long` since it must be at least 64 bits according to standard. But as said it depends on the domain of the input and maybe a big int type must be implemented.

Comment: @Osiris: What the standard says about `long long` depends on which standard (e.g. ANSI C, C89, or C99 or later). For some of these, if `long long` exists at all it's an implementation defined non-standard extension. For practical purposes, (if `long long` exists) the only built-in types with larger range are floating point types so "larger range" either implies "floating point" or a non-built-in type.

Comment: @Brendan `therefore i suggested to use a type with larger range` refers to my suggestion to use `long long` instead of `int`, not to use an integral type with larger range than `long long`.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that `k > 0`

We search fo n such as `n^3(a/n^2 + b log2(n)/n^2 + c)= k`

It is necessary to treat several cases according to that `c> 0`, `c = 0`, `c <0`

I leave the case `c = 0` for which we would factorize rather by `nlog2(n)`

Suppose `c>0`. As `lim |a/n^2| = 0` (`n-> +oo`) and `lim |b log2(n)/n^2| = 0` (`n-> +oo`)
there exists p such as for `n>p`, `|a/n^2| < c/4` and `|b log2(n)/n^2| < c/4`

we can search programmatically for such an integer p

so `-c/4 < a/n^2 < c/4` and `-c/4 < blog2(n)/n^2 < c/4`

Thus for `n>p`, `n^3*c/2 <= k <= n^3*3*c/2` and then `2k/(3c) <= n^3 <= 2k / c`

which simplifies the search for n ...

If `c < 0` we can make a loop by incrementing n and comparing the left member with k and stopping when this member becomes negative.